# FirebaseDatabase save log on file

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-logcat

I noticed that `FirebaseDatabase` only method to manage debugging is

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG);
```

Can i get or redirect it on a my file  (myfirebaselogs.txt) ? I need to send it by email when needed to understand possible errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to get the log into a file is

```
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())));

        StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            log.append(line);
            log.append(TextConstants.newLine);
        }

        fileLog = new File("myFileLog.txt);

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileLog);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(out);

        osw.write(log.toString());
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
```

It get all the log lines from the beginning of the execution.